# Elastix Upgrade fails CentOS yum missing dependency with libwat, libgsmat, and libss7

Tags: centos, yum, elastix

I upgraded a year old vanilla Elastix box using `yum update` and `yum upgrade`.

Almost 400 packages updated but a few of them failed, including **asterisk**. At present the switchboard is working but I can't apply updated configuration from the GUI. The error produced is

`exit: 1
[FATAL] Unable to connect to Asterisk Manager from /var/lib/asterisk/bin/retrieve_conf, aborting`

I researched various topics on how to get the Asterisk Management interface username and password synched, but to not avail. So now 
I'm thinking that I can isolate the problem further if I can at least get YUM to complete as it should. The errors produced by YUM update are:

```
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
2009020507:asterisk-11.5.0-0.x86_64 from elastix-beta has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libgsmat.so.2.0.7()(64bit) is needed by package 2009020507:asterisk-11.5.0-0.x86_64 (elastix-beta)
2009020507:asterisk-11.5.0-0.x86_64 from elastix-beta has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libwat.so.1.0.24()(64bit) is needed by package 2009020507:asterisk-11.5.0-0.x86_64 (elastix-beta)
Error: Missing Dependency: libgsmat.so.2.0.7()(64bit) is needed by package 2009020507:asterisk-11.5.0-0.x86_64 (elastix-beta)
Error: Missing Dependency: libwat.so.1.0.24()(64bit) is needed by package 2009020507:asterisk-11.5.0-0.x86_64 (elastix-beta)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

I tried all the remedies mentioned, including `--skip-broken`, `package-cleanup --problems`, `package-cleanup --dupes`, and `rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest` but none of this worked.

The only bit of research led me to this Elastix "bug" related to `libss7` and `spandsp` which is resolved by saying that the EPEL package supplied version should be updated to the newest version. I don't know how to do this or if it would help.
http://bugs.elastix.org/view.php?id=1753

Our Elastix came with these repos:

```
[root@elastix3 yum.repos.d]# ls
CentOS-Base.repo       CentOS-Debuginfo.repo  commercial-addons.repo  epel-testing.repo
CentOS-Base.repo.back  CentOS-Media.repo      elastix.repo            pgdg-91-centos.repo
CentOS-Base.repo.test  CentOS-Vault.repo      epel.repo
```

When I do `yum list` I notice some oddities, for example it appears `asterisk` is installed and also present in another repo:

```
[root@elastix3 yum.repos.d]# yum list | grep asterisk
asterisk.x86_64                        2009020507:1.8.20.0-0      installed     
...
asterisk.x86_64                        2009020507:11.5.0-0        elastix-beta
```

The output for `libss7`, `libgsmat`, and `libwat`:

```
[root@elastix3 yum.repos.d]# yum list | egrep -i "libss7|libgsmat|libwat"
libgsmat.x86_64                        2.0.3-0                    installed     
libwat.x86_64                          1.0.23-0                   installed     
libss7.i386                            1.0.1-3.el5                epel          
libss7.x86_64                          1.0.1-3.el5                epel
```

So I'm guessing between all these repos I have a dependency mess and I don't know where to begin solving it.

The complete output from YUM is:

```
[root@elastix3 ~]# yum upgrade
Loaded plugins: fastestmirror
Loading mirror speeds from cached hostfile
 * addons: ftp.wa.co.za
 * base: ftp.wa.co.za
 * commercial-addons: elastix.kisiek.net
 * elastix-base: elastix.kisiek.net
 * elastix-beta: elastix.kisiek.net
 * elastix-extras: elastix.kisiek.net
 * epel: ftp.wa.co.za
 * extras: ftp.wa.co.za
 * updates: ftp.wa.co.za
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Addons
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Base
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Extras
Finished
Excluding Packages from CentOS-5 - Updates
Finished
Setting up Upgrade Process
Resolving Dependencies
--> Running transaction check
---> Package asterisk.x86_64 2009020507:11.5.0-0 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libwat.so.1.0.24()(64bit) for package: asterisk
--> Processing Dependency: libgsmat.so.2.0.7()(64bit) for package: asterisk
--> Processing Dependency: libss7.so.1()(64bit) for package: asterisk
---> Package asterisk-addons.x86_64 2009020507:11.5.0-0 set to be updated
---> Package asterisk-devel.x86_64 2009020507:11.5.0-0 set to be updated
---> Package asterisk-sounds-es.x86_64 2009020507:11.5.0-0 set to be updated
---> Package asterisk-sounds-fr.x86_64 2009020507:11.5.0-0 set to be updated
--> Running transaction check
---> Package asterisk.x86_64 2009020507:11.5.0-0 set to be updated
--> Processing Dependency: libwat.so.1.0.24()(64bit) for package: asterisk
--> Processing Dependency: libgsmat.so.2.0.7()(64bit) for package: asterisk
---> Package libss7.x86_64 0:1.0.1-3.el5 set to be updated
--> Finished Dependency Resolution
2009020507:asterisk-11.5.0-0.x86_64 from elastix-beta has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libgsmat.so.2.0.7()(64bit) is needed by package 2009020507:asterisk-11.5.0-0.x86_64 (elastix-beta)
2009020507:asterisk-11.5.0-0.x86_64 from elastix-beta has depsolving problems
  --> Missing Dependency: libwat.so.1.0.24()(64bit) is needed by package 2009020507:asterisk-11.5.0-0.x86_64 (elastix-beta)
Error: Missing Dependency: libgsmat.so.2.0.7()(64bit) is needed by package 2009020507:asterisk-11.5.0-0.x86_64 (elastix-beta)
Error: Missing Dependency: libwat.so.1.0.24()(64bit) is needed by package 2009020507:asterisk-11.5.0-0.x86_64 (elastix-beta)
 You could try using --skip-broken to work around the problem
 You could try running: package-cleanup --problems
                        package-cleanup --dupes
                        rpm -Va --nofiles --nodigest
```

Please assist! Although there is a workaround to apply the updated configuration from the command line I would really know that I've got a perfectly updated system.

Answer (score 1):

EPEL points to an older version of libss7.  Update your EPEL:

rpm -ivh http://www.mirrorservice.org/sites/dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/5/i386/epel-release-5-4.noarch.rpm